# Solr not allow search free text (semantic search)

Tags: search, solr

I indexed the data in solr from database and want to do a free text search in all the columns indexed.
Do not want to provide column names.

Answer (score 1):

[Add a catch-all `copyField` instruction](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/copying-fields.html) (for example `source="*" dest="_text_"`). This will make sure that all content is copied into the `_text_` field. Make your queries search against this field.

```
q=foo bar&qf=_text_
```

The `_text_` field is usually already defined, but otherwise configure it as a `text` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eDisMax or DisMax parser you can use the `qf` parameter to indicate what fields will be searched.

The general syntax is (via query string parameters) is:

```
q="hello+world"&qf=field1+field2+field3&defType=edismax
```

You can set this value directly on your solr_config.xml so that you don't have to pass it on every request. If you do, then your query will just be:

```
q="hello+world"&defType=edismax
```